# Passing an array with dynamic number of elements into Start-Job in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a two-dimensional array which contains dynamic number of elements in both axes.

```
$h = @(@(1,2,3), @(4,5,6,7))  

$h | %{

  $ScriptBlock = {

    param($var1, $var2) 
    Write-Host "[processing '$var1' inside the job]"  # I want a variable which can access $h[0], or $h[1] here

  }

  Write-Host "processing $_..."
  Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $_
}

# Wait for all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 2 }

# Display output from all jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job

# Cleanup
Remove-Job *
```

Is it possible to have a single variable inside `$ScriptBlock` that can access `$h[0]`, or `$h[1]`?

I know that in my code, `$var1`, and `$var2` can have access to `$h[0][0]`, `$h[0][1]` and `$h[1][0]`, `$h[1][1]`. But because the dimension of `$h` is dynamic,  using `param($var1, $var2)` is not able to have access to all of the elements in `$h`.

Anyone how to do this?

Comment: You can try to omit the param section within your scriptblock and use `$using:h` to access the variable outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that using `$args` can get access to `$h[0]`, and `$h[1]`.

Remember to remove `param($var1, $var2)` line.

```
$h = @(@(1,2,3), @(4,5,6,7))  

$h | %{

  $ScriptBlock = {

    write-host $args     # access $h[0], $h[1]
    write-host $args[0]  # access $h[0][0], $h[1][0]
  }

  Write-Host "processing $_..."
  Start-Job $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $_
}

# Wait for all to complete
While (Get-Job -State "Running") { Start-Sleep 2 }

# Display output from all jobs
Get-Job | Receive-Job

# Cleanup
Remove-Job *
```